# Create overall IoC container

Tags: c#, ioc-container, bootstrapper

I use IoC container in my project, but my project contains many submodules. And I would like use one base IoC module.
Example:
I have two interfaces in submodule **A**
It is IOne and ITwo interfaces

```
public interface ITwo
{
     // some code
}

public interface IOne
{
     // some code
}
```

And my **SimpleInjectorRegisterTypes** class

```
public class SimpleInjectorRegisterTypes : ISimpleInjectorRegistration
    {
        public void Register(Container container)
        {
            container.RegisterSingle<ITwo, Two>();
            container.RegisterSingle<IOne, One>();
        }
    }
```

And main class, where I use my logic

```
private static IOne _one;
        private static ITwo _two;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Container container = new Container();
            new SimpleInjectorRegisterTypes().Register(container);
            _one= container.GetInstance<IOne>();
            _two= container.GetInstance<ITwo>();
        }
```

It is good, but i have submodule **B** where I have interfaces IThree and TFour
and also SimpleInjectorRegisterTypes and main class.
How to write a general IoC container for all my submodules?
P.S. For IoC I use [bootstrapper](https://bootstrapper.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Why would you want to register dependencies in multiple places? Why not do all the 'bootstrapping' in your application entry point?

Comment: so you have: a Container where you register your interfaces/class pairs, then you have a interface/class pair just doing said registration - then you use all that only to create two static instances of your interfaces in a static class .... isn't that **a bit** overkill?

Comment: I have independent modules and i have (if it is possibly) create one overall IoC container, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that there are 3 sub assemblies say, `Common`, `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`.

- `Common` has `ICommon` interface and your `ISimpleInjectorRegistration` interface.
- `ModuleA` has `CommonA` implements `ICommon`, and its independent registrations(`IOne`:`One`, `ITwo`:`Two`)
- `ModuleB` has `CommonB` implements `ICommon`, and its registrations(`IThree`:`Three`, `IFour`:`Four`)

`ModuleA` register like this:

```
public class RegistrationA : ISimpleInjectorRegistration
{
    public void Register(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<IOne, One>();
        container.Register<ITwo, Two>();
        container.Register<ICommon, CommonA>();
        container.RegisterAll<ICommon>(typeof(CommonA));
    }
}
```

And `ModuleB` register like this:

```
public class RegistrationB : ISimpleInjectorRegistration
{
    public void Register(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<IThree, Three>();
        container.Register<IFour, Four>();
        container.Register<ICommon, CommonB>();
        container.RegisterAll<ICommon>(typeof (CommonB));
    }
}
```

Now, in the Main module you might do like this:

```
var container = new Container();
new ModuleA.RegistrationA().Register(container);
new ModuleB.RegistrationB().Register(container);
container.Verify();
```

But it fails on the `ModuleB` registration, because `ICommon` was duplicated in both registrations.

You can avoid duplicated registration and force to replace to latest one by using `Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations`:

```
var container2 = new Container();
container2.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = true;
new ModuleA.Registration().Register(container2);
new ModuleB.Registration().Register(container2);
container2.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = false;
container2.Verify();

var commonInstance2 = container2.GetInstance<ICommon>();
var commonInstances2 = container2.GetAllInstances<ICommon>();
```

As a result, `commonInstance2` will be an instance of `CommonB` and `commonInstances2` will be a sequence of `ICommon` that contains single `CommonB` instance.

You might want to get `CommonA` as a `ICommon`. Or get all implementations of `ICommon` as a `IEnumerable<ICommon>`:

```
var container3 = new Container();
container3.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = true;
new ModuleA.Registration().Register(container3);
new ModuleB.Registration().Register(container3);

// you can choose which ICommon should be registered.
container3.Register<ICommon, ModuleA.CommonA>();

// or collect all implementation of ICommon
// (of course using Assembly.GetTypes() is better solution)
container3.RegisterAll<ICommon>(typeof (ModuleA.CommonA), typeof (ModuleB.CommonB));

container3.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = false;
container3.Verify();

var commonInstance3 = container3.GetInstance<ICommon>();
var commonInstances3 = container3.GetAllInstances<ICommon>();
```

As a result, `commonInstance3` will be the `CommonA` instance and `commonInstances3` will contain both `CommonA` and `CommonB` instances.

The point is, you should keep simple when register dependencies. Only one place will be ideal, but if you have independent modules and each modules are not aware of each others, the 'Main' who knows both modules should configure the registrations correctly.